# Can I load a post single page from my plugin directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

As a wp plugin developer, I want to load a post single page from my plugin directory. Not a custom post type I want to load from the default wp post type.[function.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqWmS.png) [template.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSLtH.png)

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438987/trying-to-add-a-custom-post-type-page-template-from-plugin-into-sage-10-theme/72442671#72442671

Comment: Already I tried it. But not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook to check if this is a single page and the post type is 'post'

```
add_action( 'single_template', [$this, 'event_single_page'] );
function event_single_page( $single ) {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type == 'post' &&  is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
            $plugin_template = 'post-single-page.php';
            if ( file_exists( $plugin_template ) ) {
                $single = $plugin_template ;
            }
        }
        return $single;
    }
```